# Gradle fails to resolve dependencies in Android Studio ( cupboard library )

Tags: android, database

When I try to add cupboard library with gradle by this line:

```
compile 'nl.qbusict:cupboard:(insert latest version)'
```

I have this error in Gradle sync:

> Failed to resolve: nl

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this:

> compile 'nl.qbusict:cupboard:2.1.1'

Comment: @ahmedhamdy Accept my answer it If it's worked and helped you. ;P